# pandas - adding aggregated feature

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe in pandas:

```
   day customer  amount
0    1    cust1     500
1    2    cust2     100
2    1    cust1      50
3    2    cust1     100
4    2    cust2     250
5    6    cust1      20
```

I would like to create a new column 'amount2days' so as to aggragate amounts per customer for the last two days, to get the following dataframe:

```
   day customer  amount    amount2days   ----------------------------
0    1    cust1     500    500           (no past transactions)
1    2    cust2     100    100           (no past transactions)
2    1    cust1      50    550           (500 + 50 = rows 0,2 
3    2    cust1     100    650           (500 + 50 + 100, rows 0,2,3)
4    2    cust2     250    350           (100 + 250, rows 1,4) 
5    6    cust1      20    20            (notice day is 6, and no day=5 for cust1)
```

i.e. I would like to perform the following (pseudo) code:

```
df['amount2days'] = df_of_past_2_days['amount'].sum()
```

for each row. What is the most convenient way to do so?

The summing I wish to peroform is over the day, but days does not necessarily have to increment in each new row, as shown in the example. Still I want to sum amounts over the past 2 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's just rolling on days:

```
def get_roll(x):
    s = pd.Series(x['amount'].values, 
                  index=pd.to_datetime('1900-01-01') + pd.to_timedelta(x['day'], unit='D')
                 )
    return pd.Series(s.rolling('2D').sum().values, index=x.index)

df['amount2days'] = (df.groupby('customer').apply(get_roll)
                       .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
                    )
```

Output:

```
   day customer  amount  amount2days
1    1    cust1     500        500.0
2    1    cust2     100        100.0
3    1    cust1      50        550.0
4    2    cust1     100        650.0
5    2    cust2     250        350.0
6    3    cust1      20        120.0
```

---

**Option 2**: Since you are looking to take cumulative sum on just two days, the amount today is added by that of the previous day only. So we can utilize `shift`:

```
df['amount2days'] = df.groupby(['customer','day'])['amount'].cumsum()

# shift the last item of the previous day and add
df['amount2days'] += (df.drop_duplicates(['day','customer'],keep='last')
   .groupby(['customer'])['amount2days'].shift()
   .reindex(df.index)
   .ffill()
   .fillna(0)
)
```

Comment: unfortunately not, notice that in the 4th row the sum needs to be 650 (summing over days 1 and 2 which is 500 + 50 + 100

Comment: Is `day` just number or is it `datetime` type? You have the option of `rolling('2D')` on `datetime` type.

Comment: `day` is just a number

Comment: @user112112 See updated answer for a modified version which utilizes rolling by Day.